# Cross Referencig for tables and plots in R Markdown is not working

Tags: r, reference, r-markdown

I am dealing with this problem, I am trying to follow several sources in the forum. But I cant solve this issue.

I want to reference plots and tables in an R markdown document:

I have included in the yaml section this:  (bookdown added)

```
---
title: "Demo"
author:
- Me
date: "2023-05-04"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
  number_sections: true
  fig_caption: TRUE
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  word_document: 
    pandoc_args:
      - '--lua-filter=parse-latex.lua'
bibliography: referencias.bib
---
```

Then for example I have the next chunck with a table:

````
  ```{r overal-male,caption = "Dynamic effects, overall male population" ,     
warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,echo=FALSE,fig.align="center",fig.pos='H',eval=TRUE}


   #overall_male table
   overall_male$agmod|>tidy()|>select(event.time,estimate,std.error,conf.low,conf.high)|>
   mutate(sig=ifelse(conf.high<0,"*","-"))|>format(digits = 2)|>
   kable(format = "latex",booktabs=TRUE) |> 
   kable_styling(position = "center",latex_options = "HOLD_position")


 ```
````

As you see I have included the label (overal-male) and a caption as I found in the documentation.

THen I call the next cross reference:  @ref(tab:overal-male)

But I am still getting ??. Additionally, I am getting the next warning that I dont understand:

Warning: LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:overal-male' on page 6 undefined on input line 326.

Why in that line? I have been checking the code in this line but I cant see nothing related.

I have the same issue with the figures.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAYcN.png)

Best regards.

I am trying a lot of things.
I have included in the yaml section the bookdown
I have added caption and label
I am calling the reference by @ref(fig:label) or  @ref(fig:label)

But I still have the same error.

I dont know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The LaTex warning is referring to the line in the generated LaTex file not the markdown. You can see this by adding `keep_tex: true` under   `bookdown::pdf_document2: default`.

The issue is that the kable function is not automatically creating a label (which you will see in the LaTex file). You can resolve this by changing `kable()` to `kable(caption = "")`.